# Where are the OpenCv3.10 libraries?

Tags: opencv3.1

I have just downloaded OpenCv3.10 and the only libraries in the `lib` directory
are:

`opencv_world310.lib`

and

`opencv_world310d.lib`.

Why arent there any other?

Comment: that is a library that contains all the others... you just need only this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but i cant build my project like this because although i linked opencv-world310.lib to release and opencv_world310d.lib to debug under linker settings under build option i get a undefined reference error to `cvRound`